# How to stop Python ElementTree from doing <element /> instead of <element></element>?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I've got a Python class that creates a manifest file in xml using xml.etree.ElementTree for a product's software. The problem is that when I do:

```
self.manifestTree.write(pathAndFilename, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

The problem is that it produces elements like:

```
<element />
```

rather than:

```
<element></element>
```

for empty elements. And even if both are syntactically valid, the product I am working on parses it as incorrect and alarms appear. Modifying the parser is not an option because this is a legacy product and all I am trying to do is automate the build process.

How could I tell ElementTree to produce `<element></element>` instead of `<element />`?

I thought about opening the file once it is created and using regex to find the element and edit that line, but it is not as trivial as I initially thought.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: The better option is to fix that product; valid XML is still valid XML.

Comment: Agreed. Not an option though.

Comment: Well, lets hope your XML uses only lowercase tagnames then. :-P